# Python type hint/annotation for code objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting, python-typing

Is there a Python type hint/annotation for code objects (as returned by `compile` on source code strings, or the result of calling the `__code__` attribute on a method)? I have a method which accepts a single code object argument, and I want to annotate it appropriately using appropriately the `typing` library.

```
>>> c = compile('x = 1', 'test', 'single')
>>> <code object <module> at 0x1075f8660, file "test", line 1>
>>> c
>>> code
>>> type(c)
>>> type
>>> typing.get_type_hints(c)
>>> {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it is available in the module `types`:

```
from types import CodeType
code: CodeType = compile('x = 1', 'test', 'single')
```